# Not able to find right query in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have been trying to come up with a query for these (simplified) documents below. My database consists of several data similar as these.

Since there is no nested querying in Mongo shell, is there another possible way to get what I want?

I am trying to get a list of Medicines that are owned by more than 30% of the pharmacies in my DB (regardless of quantity).

```
[
  {
    "Pharmacy": "a",
    "Medicine": [
      {
        "MedName": "MedA",
        "Quantity": 55
      },
      {
        "MedName": "MedB",
        "Quantity": 34
      },
      {
        "MedName": "MedD",
        "Quantity": 25
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Pharmacy": "b",
    "Medicine": [
      {
        "MedName": "MedB",
        "Quantity": 60
      },
      {
        "MedName": "MedC",
        "Quantity" : 34
      }

    ]
  }
]
```

How can I do this (if possible)?

Comment: hi, can you provide complete document schema (not just the array)

Comment: Why would the other fields be important in this case?

Comment: some queries wan be different with nested arrays and documents

Comment: Do you mean this whole array is part of a bigger document? If so then it isn't, the documents are each pharmacy records with a bit more simple fields. I just added two sample records

Comment: ok, and what can i do if i need  to unwind your array, but don't have the array name? Just provide infos, or don't ask any help!

Comment: there is not 'two samples records" in your example, but one array with 2 objects

Comment: My bad the array wrappers In the beginning and end are just so that I could easily "prettify" my document. The actual record is pharmacy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the answer here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/KVZ4Ee9Qhu-

```
var PharmaCount = db.collection.count();


db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$Medicine"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "medName": "$Medicine.MedName",
      "Pharmacy": "$Pharmacy"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "medName": "$medName"
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "count": 1,
      "percentage": {
        "$concat": [
          {
            "$substr": [
              {
                "$multiply": [
                  {
                    "$divide": [
                      "$count",
                      {
                        "$literal": 2 // Your total number of pharmacies i.e PharmaCount
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  100
                ]
              },
              0,
              3
            ]
          },
          "",
          "%"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You should get results like:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "medName": "MedC"
    },
    "count": 1,
    "percentage": "50%"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "medName": "MedD"
    },
    "count": 1,
    "percentage": "50%"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "medName": "MedB"
    },
    "count": 2,
    "percentage": "100%"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "medName": "MedA"
    },
    "count": 1,
    "percentage": "50%"
  }
]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this does help a lot. But what should I do if I need to limit my output to the ones above a certain percentage?

Comment: Nevermind I have added this to $match : {count : {$gte : MathCiel(PharmaCount*0.15)} which has given me exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this in a single query, but here is a way :

```
size = (db['01'].distinct("Pharmacy")).length;
minPN = Math.ceil(size*0.3);

db['01'].aggregate(
    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $unwind: {
                path : "$Medicine", 
            }
        },
        // Stage 2
        {
            $group: {
            _id:"$Medicine.MedName",
            pharmacies:{$addToSet:"$Pharmacy"}
            }
        },
        // Stage 3
        {
            $project: {
              pharmacies:1,
            pharmacies_count:{$size:"$pharmacies"}
            }
        },
        {
          $match:{pharmacies_count:{$gte:minPN}}
        }   
    ]
);
```